# Meaning of "eventlets"

Tags: word-meaning, literature

What was the thing? They pointed out these **eventlets** to each other. They
did not discuss or pass judgment, but defined themselves against the
attitudes revealed by the unwitting characters in these dramas. They wanted
to know each other less than they wanted to agree. Harmony! To be each other.

What is the meaning of "eventlets"? Does it mean "eventless"?

Source: *The Children's Bach* by Helen Garner

Comment: It's a whimsical nonce-word - probably made up *at time of speaking*, but feasibly the speaker might be repeating something he picked up from someone else. Suffixes ***-let*** and ***-ette*** (compare [***jobettte***](http://therelationshipdeal.com/2014/02/27/do-stay-at-home-dads-have-a-jobette/)) just imply "small version of preceding noun").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suffix -let means a smaller version of something. For example, booklets and droplets are smaller versions of books and drops.

The author has extended the idea to invent the word "eventlets," which is a smaller version of an event. It is shorter and/or less significant than regular events.